Azure Powershell - how to list all Environment variables
In Azure Portal I have several "Function apps" and "App Services" that have Environment variables. Environment variables can have "App Settings" and "Connections strings".
I like to list "Environment Variables", for all services, by Name and Value.
My goal is to check for any wrong settings so I like all "Environment Variables" in a long list.
How can I do this from Azure Cloud Shell?
Thanks,

Could you confirm whether your requirement is to fetch these Environment variables via PowerShell? https://i.imgur.com/MX0S80I.png

Yes. Correct settings.

You want to export the data to csv file like this https://i.imgur.com/QYBEMM0.png or print on terminal like this https://i.imgur.com/oOGDDvY.png?

Print in terminal is ok. I can then copy to Notepad++ and check values.

Sure, please do that

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Hi @Henrik Any update?

Hi @Henrik Please click on checkmark beside the answer and upvote if it's helpful for you in any way

To list all Environment variables from all App Services and Function Apps, you can make use of below sample PowerShell script:
Connect-AzAccount

$rGs = Get-AzResourceGroup
$allSettings = @()

foreach ($rg in $rGs) {
    $webApps = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $rg.ResourceGroupName

    foreach ($webApp in $webApps) {
        $appSettings = (Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $rg.ResourceGroupName -Name $webApp.Name).SiteConfig.AppSettings
        foreach ($setting in $appSettings) {
            $allSettings += [pscustomobject]@{
                ServiceName     = $webApp.Name
                ResourceGroup   = $rg.ResourceGroupName
                SettingName     = $setting.Name
                SettingValue    = $setting.Value
                SettingType     = "AppSetting"
            }
        }

        $connectionStrings = (Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $rg.ResourceGroupName -Name $webApp.Name).SiteConfig.ConnectionStrings
        foreach ($conn in $connectionStrings) {
            $allSettings += [pscustomobject]@{
                ServiceName     = $webApp.Name
                ResourceGroup   = $rg.ResourceGroupName
                SettingName     = $conn.Name
                SettingValue    = $conn.ConnectionString
                SettingType     = "ConnectionString"
            }
        }
    }
}

$allSettings | Export-Csv -Path "$HOME/AllEnvironmentVariables.csv" -NoTypeInformation #exported to csv file
$allSettings # print values to terminal

Response:

AllEnvironmentVariables.csv:


You can use the following Azure CLI commands to list configuration settings of App Services and Function Apps.
App Services:

az webapp config show: Get the details of a web app's configuration
az webapp config appsettings list: Get the details of a web app's settings

Function Apps:

az functionapp config show: Get the details of an existing function app's configuration
az functionapp config appsettings list: Show settings for a function app

If you need to filter variables by type (App Settings, Azure SQL Database connection strings, custom connection strings, etc) take a look into the variable prefixes.
